# Vim директория по умолчанию (nerdtree)

Tags: vim

При старте vim, в nerdtree открывается путь с папкой vim, а мне нужна папка где лежит проект.

nnoremap  :NERDTreeToggle C:...\Project

Нашел только такое решение, но что то не работает, при нажатии на f7 окно с каталогами закрывается и все. Как установить пусть по умалчанию

Comment: Чутка криво скопипастил: nnoremap <F7> :NERDTreeToggle C:\...

Answer (score 2):

В файле .vimrc

для открытия в текушем каталоге

```
nmap <F2> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
vmap <F2> <esc>:NERDTreeToggle<cr>
imap <F2> <esc>:NERDTreeToggle<cr>
```

для открытия в нужном каталоге

```
nmap <F3> :NERDTreeToggle  /c/work/project <cr>
vmap <F3> <esc>:NERDTreeToggle /c/work/project <cr>
imap <F3> <esc>:NERDTreeToggle /c/work/project <cr>
```

Comment: В данном случае /с/ это обозначение диска С: ? Слеш должен быть в таком направлении / ? Просто после добавления этих строк, результат такой же как и в первом вопросе, просто закрывается\открывается дерево в папке /user/vim, и в строке состояния написано /c/work/project

Comment: UPD
Все заработало когда отключил автозапуск nerdtree при старте vim. Можно ли сделать что бы NT и запускался сам, и путь был не дефолтным?

Comment: UPD проблема решена  
 autocmd vimenter * :NERDTreeToggle  C:\Users\Dimakss\Dropbox. Только нужно убрать строку autocmd vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif (если копипастили настройки как я)

Comment: Я использую msys2, в нем можно использовать запись пути на манер как в linux `/c/work` вместо `C:\work`